# How to insert a tikz image in the same page as the part title page?

Tags: tikz-pgf, titles, page-breaking, parts

I have created a new command for drawing a **tikz** image and I want to insert it on the same page as the **part title page**.

[image: Image created with tikz]
[image: I want to put the tikz image over the title of this page]

I now have this image on a page before the **part title page**, and what I want is to **prevent the page break from occurring when invoking the command that causes the tikz code to execute**.

**EDIT 1___________________________________________________________**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,twoside,reqno]{extbook}
\usepackage[margin=28mm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathpazo}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{tikz, ifthen, bclogo}
\usepackage{pst-poly}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals,calc} \usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,patterns,shadows,petri,decorations.markings,shapes,trees}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\usepackage{latexsym, graphicx}
\usepackage[thicklines, makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{stmaryrd, scalerel, stackengine}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{underoverlap}
\usepackage{theorem}
\usepackage{secdot}
\usepackage{empheq}
```

....................

**EDIT 2: Minimal working example ________________________________________**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,twoside,reqno]{extbook}
\usepackage[margin=28mm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathpazo}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft, etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz, ifthen, bclogo}

%______________<<< tikz example >>>_________________
\newcommand{\geo} {
    \usetikzlibrary {shapes.geometric}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (start) [draw,shape=ellipse] {};
        \foreach \angle in {-180, -178, ..., 180}
        \draw (node cs:name=start,angle=\angle)
        .. controls +(\angle:5cm) and +(0,0) .. (0,5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
% -------------------------------------oOo-------------------------------------
\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{plain}
    \newpage
    \begin{center}
        \geo
    \end{center}
    \part{Sequences $ \& $ Series.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This will probably be dependent on your document class and packages you use that have an effect on how the `\part` page will be created. (And possibly how your custom TikZ picture is created.)

Comment: See the edit of my question!

Comment: Edit 1 is both too much and too little.  It tels us more about tons of packages that have no bearing on the problem, and nothing about the tikzicture.  Extbook is useful since it defines \part.